# how to edit JNI generated header file

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

I have an auto jni header file created with javah. Now i want to edit this header file and add/edit some functions. What is the best way to manually edit the jni header file?
Things that i really need to know is:
**how to correctly map the variables and pointers between c/c++ and java.**

---

For example if i have a function in my c/c++ project like this:

```
int test(unsigned int * id,unsigned char name[8],const unsigned char input[13])
```

now what are the mapping between int,char,const...,string,pointers, etc...

```
 /*
 * Class:     First
 * Method:    test
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_First_test (JNIEnv *, jobject, /*what should i add here?*/);
```

Comment: FYI, we can avoid having to deal with JNI using a tool like [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).

Comment: Why? Just write another header file and include them both in your .c or .cpp file. Don't mess around with generated code.

Comment: @EJP this is what exactly i want to do. i have a complete c++ project and now i want to use that in java. now how can i manually write the header file to export the dll to java?

Comment: You are doing it backwards. Design the Java classes based on the concepts in the C++ project.

Comment: @TomBlodget yep! do you know any document? or can you provide me an easy sample?

Comment: Your Java program needs a facility that does XXX. Write a Java interface or class that provides it in a natural Java way. This step has nothing to do with JNI. Add that code to your question.

Comment: @osyan You don't 'export a DLL to Java'. You use the functions in the DLL in a JNI DLL that Java calls. You write a Java class with native methods, then you use the `javah` tool to write the header file, then you write a corresponding .cpp file that implements those methods. Or, if you're only calling Java from C++ and not the other way round, you just use the JNI Invocation API in your C++ code and there are no Java native methods and no generated header file at all. Either way there is certainly no occasion for editing the generated header file. Your question basically doesn't make sense.